# Django debug error page not working on AJAX calls

Tags: python, django

A great feature of django is the debug page returned on On 500 errors.

However, on AJAX calls I get the plain text error that one would expect to get when `DEBUG = False`. This problem does not happen when executing non AJAX requests: on 'normal' request if an internet server error happens then the nice debug page is returned.

I upgraded upgrade from django 1.3 to 1.5 yesterday.

My settings.py has the folllowing:

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS contain django.core.context_processors.debug
```

I have reset my `settings.py` to 'factory settings' but the problem persists.

example of most simple code affected - see even the most simple of code is affected:

```
def webservice(request):
     raise KeyError
     return HttpResponse('it didnt work')
```

This is called by the following request:

```
$.post('/webservice/', {'a':1, 'b':2})
```

Must be noted that I am using jquery, and this little baby so csrf_token is added to the requests:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings) {
        function sameOrigin(url) {
            var host = document.location.host, // host + port
                protocol = document.location.protocol,
                sr_origin = '//' + host,
                origin = protocol + sr_origin;
            return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + '/') ||
                (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
                // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
                !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
        }
        function safeMethod(method) {
            return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
        }
        if (!safeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", '{{csrf_token}}');
        }
    });
```

**SOLUTION FOR POSTERITY**

behaviour changed in 1.4 to only return traceback when request is ajax. Below is how to optionally bring the feature back (which is very useful when you work mainly in the domain of ajax requests):

edit `django.views.debug` line 65 from

```
if request.is_ajax():
```

to

`if request.is_ajax() and settings.MINIFY_505_ON_AJAX`:

then add `MINIFY_505_ON_AJAX = False` in `settings.py`

Comment: Please include the code for one of your AJAX requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "nice debug page" depends on the DEBUG setting (from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#debug)

```
One of the main features of debug mode is the display of detailed error pages.
If your app raises an exception when DEBUG is True, Django will display a 
detailed traceback, including a lot of metadata about your environment, such
as all the currently defined Django settings (from settings.py).
```

TEMPLATE_DEBUG adds extra information related to template rendering errors.

**UPDATE**:

That's the way it's supposed to work if request.is_ajax() is true then a text traceback is returned in the response body, check the source:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/debug.py#L59-70

This behavior was changed in 1.4, commit: https://github.com/django/django/commit/0d9b6a5bc43c06716212bd3f847460ce985381aa

**UPDATE 2**:

It's kinda hackish but for debugging purposes you could modify the HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header so request.is_ajax() is false, then forcing the html response. (See https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/request.py#L136-137)

Comment: My settings.py has the folllowing:

DEBUG = True

Also, the problem only happens on AJAX requests.

Comment: @rikAtee: That's not a problem, that's the way it's meant to be, check my update with a link to the source.

Comment: you are awesome! thanks. I did the following:

edited `technical_500_response` to `if request.is_ajax() and settings.MINIFY_505_ON_AJAX:` and in settings added MINIFY_505_ON_AJAX=False

This is a more maintainable fix, and what is django meant to be if not maintainable!

Answer (score 1):

The `TEMPLATE_DEBUG` option only works for errors that occur while rendering a Django template. Since your function does not render any templates, the option will have no effect.

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-debug:

> A boolean that turns on/off template debug mode. If this is True, the
>   fancy error page will display a detailed report for any exception
>   raised during **template rendering**. This report contains the relevant
>   snippet of the template, with the appropriate line highlighted.

This also means that even if your function does render a template, if the error occurs before the template is rendered you will still end up with the plain-text output.

Note that in the following example:

```
def year_archive(request, year):
    a_list = Article.objects.filter(pub_date__year=year)
    raise Exception("something horrible happened")
    return render_to_response('news/year_archive.html', {'year': year, 'article_list': a_list})
```

The `Exception` is being raised before `render_to_response`, so `TEMPLATE_DEBUG` will never have a chance to run.

If you want to see the traceback for a non-template error, you will need to look at the command line output or the logs.

Comment: hmm - odd. in django 1.3 I was getting full fancy debug page.

Comment: The functionality seems to have changed since 1.3. Here is what that version of the documentation said: "A boolean that turns on/off template debug mode. If this is True, the fancy error page will display a detailed report for any TemplateSyntaxError. This report contains the relevant snippet of the template, with the appropriate line highlighted."

Comment: I used the provided example code and still get the fancy debug page:

http://i.imgur.com/QCOBCdr.png

Comment: Interesting. I would guess that happens regardless of whether TEMPLATE_DEBUG is True/False.

Comment: indeed I have. I have done the likes of NameError, ZeroDivisionError, etc

Comment: I see. If I remember correctly, Django has special case logic for dealing with requests where Content-Type:application/json is present. Their thinking is that an AJAX request should always return JSON, not HTML as it might cause clients to behave weirdly.